# Technology behind adding text or image on a video at real time?

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, video, cloud, video-processing

When we try designing a t-shirt with [www.zazzle.com](http://www.zazzle.com) (from menu, Create Your Own > Clothing & Accessories > T-Shirts), and add text or image, then we see Zazzle putting the same text or image on the model's video at real time.

Alternately, check out [www.smartmockups.com](http://www.smartmockups.com)

*What is the algorithm or technology behind putting text or image on a video? Is there any cloud service which will allow me to achieve similar functionality?*